# Arduino serial monitor does not show anything for AT command

Tags: arduino, hc-05, serial-monitor

I am a beginner to arduino and trying to follow one of the videos from youtube to make a project- Master And Slave using HC-05 modules. I followed every step from that video carefully. Here's the link to the video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXXAcFOTnBo For Slave Module when I type AT commands in the serial monitor nothing shows up. I searched in Internet for the this problem and still didn't fix it. Here's What i have done:

tired restarting my pc
tried Changing arduino, At first i used arduino nano and then uno
I tried changing the baud rate to all other values and nothing happened
And there is no change in light blink, it stays on AT command mode until power is turned off and on again.

[This is how is looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnnaP.png)

Thank You For the Answer

Comment: can you make a change between tx - rx and try again?

Comment: Sure, yes I was tried that! But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not responding to `AT` commands is common with cloned `HC-05` modules. The biggest reason for this is that the `ENABLED` pin is not plugged in. Right next to the `VCC` pin, there is a pin called `KEY` that should be idle. When you feed that pin with 3.3V, you will see that you get a response to the `AT` commands. If you don't get any response, don't forget to press the button on the BT Module after making the connection. If that doesn't work, be sure to remove the EN pin and press the button again. You should try these ways until you get a response from the AT command. Every time you write `AT` on the serial port screen, the bluetooth module will also respond to these requests with the led on it.